# Spark 1.6 - Alternative solution for Unionall operation?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

Have 4 DF called df1,df2,df3 and df4 . All DF's are same schema type . requirment is i need to do union all the DF. So

```
val res1 = df1.unionAll(df2).unionAll(df3).unionAll(df4).distinct()
```

Getting Non-Zero exit 143. Have any better solution to rewrite above code. Every df have > 20 M of records

Answer (score 0):

I tried a similar command and it works for me , so nothing wrong with the command .

You mentioned that the exit code of 143 , is this related to Java heap ? If yes then you can try to increase the cluster size and see if that help . If not please share the full error text /